# Custom Lightning Page Template Fit To Console App Window?

Tags: page-template

I'm trying to create a lightning page template for a record page that will be viewed in a console app. I want a 2 column layout in which the columns are the size of the console app visible window and the columns overflow so each column can be scrolled through. Default page templates do this, but I will need a custom one to allow modification and have not been able to figure it out.

[image: default template example]
Above is an image of what im trying to achieve (although with 2 columns). Each column overflows and has an independent scroll bar. There is no page scroll bar. However, when I do something like this

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:appHomeTemplate">
    <aura:attribute name="left" type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="right" type="Aura.Component[]" />

    <div style="height: 100%; display: block;">
        <div style="display: flex; height: 100%;">
            <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
                {!v.left}
            </div>
            <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
                {!v.right}
            </div>
        </div>     
    </div>  
</aura:component>
```

the containers height is not set to the visible console window and the divs containing the aura component arrays do not overflow. I'm left with a scrollable window instead of 2 scrollable columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve it after using standard `lightning:layout` component and a bit of CSS tweaking.

**Component**:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:recordHomeTemplate" description="Scrollable colums">
<aura:attribute name="left" type="Aura.Component[]" />
<aura:attribute name="right" type="Aura.Component[]" />

<lightning:layout class="container" pullToBoundary="medium">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6"
                          class="slds-m-right_small scroll-y">
        {!v.left}
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6"
                          class="slds-m-left_small scroll-y">
        {!v.right}
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS.container {
    max-height: 75vh;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%
}

.THIS .scroll-y {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I used vh to set the height, but since the header and footer in Salesforce are fixed height, changing the window size causes the columns to get cut off. I think I can get around that by doing height: calc(78vh - footerheightpx - headerheightpx); or something of that nature. Since sandboxes have the extra banner at the top to display the sandbox name, the sizing will be different in a sanbox vs production server. I was hoping there would be a more robust solution

Answer (score 1):

Piggy backing off of Anmol's response: The only way I have been able achieve my ask is to set the height of the columns to 100vh minus the header and footer heights. This is not ideal since the Salesforce header is larger in sandboxes (due to the sandbox name banner) than production. The following seems to do the trick.

```
Height: calc(100vh - 193px);
```

193px is the size of the Salesforce header, footer, and a little extra so the columns don't scroll into the footer. This will look a little off in a sandbox, but if you remove the sandbox banner manually and test it, it will scale properly.